# Extract a call stack from a Windows minidump on linux

Tags: debugging, pdb-files, minidump, dmp

I'm writing a crash report system for a medium size application. The applications runs on Windows and generates dmp files when crashing but the crash report system is currently running on Linux. If I open the minidump in Visual Studio with the correct symbolstore (with pdb files) set up it gives me a great call stack.

I'm looking for a way to extract this call stack on a linux machine or another way that I could implement in the Linux based crash report system.

I have looked at the Symbolic project by Sentry but I'm not sure how to use it.
https://github.com/getsentry/symbolic

Any ideas on how I could achieve this or do I need to extract the call stack on a windows machine?